# Converting .Net API to PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have this .Net REST API function modified from the demo for a grid control here: http://gijgo.com/grid/demos/ajax-sourced-data.
However, I am using PHP on the backend.

```
public JsonResult Get(int? page, int? limit)
{
    List<Models.inventory> records;
    int total;
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var query = context.inventory.Select(p => new Models.inventory
        {
            id = p.id,
            company = p.company,
            part = p.part,
            year = p.year,
            model = p.model,
            stock = p.stock,
            ic = p.ic,
            vin = p.vin,
            status = p.status,
            bodycolor = p.bodycolor,
            condition = p.condition,
            comments = p.comments,
            miles = p.miles,
            price = p.price,
            qty = p.qty
        });

        query = query.OrderBy(q => q.id);

        total = query.Count();

        if (page.HasValue && limit.HasValue)
        {
            int start = (page.Value - 1) * limit.Value;
            records = query.Skip(start).Take(limit.Value).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            records = query.ToList();
        }
    }

    return this.Json(new { records, total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have converted the function to PHP but am having difficulty with the pagination because the total records isn't really being sent.
The C# code, filters the data after the query and i'm not sure how to do that with PHP and PostgreSQL.

I also want to return the total number of rows without the limit and offset in the result I suppose I'm going to have to run a 2nd query to return that data,
is that correct or can I do it in another way?

```
private function GetInventory()
{
    $ic=$_request['ic'];
    $limit=$_request['limit'];
    $offset=$_request['page']-1;

    $sql = "SELECT u.id, "
        .  "   (SELECT company FROM urgss.users WHERE id = u.id) AS company, "
        .  "   u.itemname || ' (' || u.part || ')' as part, "
        .  "   u.year, "
        .  "   u.model, "
        .  "   u.stockno AS stock, "
        .  "   u.ic AS ic, "
        .  "   u.vin, "
        .  "   u.status || ' / ' || u.currentstatus AS status, "
        .  "   REGEXP_REPLACE(u.bod_col, '[\[\]]', '', 'g') AS bodycolor, "
        .  "   u.condition, "
        .  "   u.comments, "
        .  "   CASE "
        .  "   WHEN u.miles::integer < 1000 THEN "
        .  "                  u.miles::INTEGER * 1000 "
        .  "           ELSE "
        .  "                  u.miles::INTEGER "
        .  "           END AS miles, "
        .  "   CASE "
        .  "      WHEN u.rprice > 0 THEN "
        .  "           u.rprice "
        .  "      ELSE "
        .  "          NULL "
        .  "      END AS price, "
        .  "   u.qty "
        .  "FROM unet u "
        .  "WHERE ic = '" . $ic. "' "
        .  "AND year::integer > 0"
        .  " LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET ". ($offset * $limit);
    $result = pg_exec($db, $sql);
    $rows = pg_fetch_all($result);
    echo  json_encode($rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `LIMIT` from the query (REMOVE THIS `.  " LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET ". ($offset * $limit);`), then there are two options:

Instead of `pg_fetch_all` you could fetch in a loop and specify the `$row_num` based on offset and limit:

```
//get total number of rows
$total = pg_num_rows($result);
//get rows from offset up to limit
$row_num = $offset;
while($row_num < ($offset + $limit) && $rows[] = pg_fetch_assoc($result, $row_num)) {
    $row_num++;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Or `pg_fetch_all` and slice what you want:

```
//get total number of rows
$total = pg_num_rows($result);
//get ALL rows
$rows = pg_fetch_all($result);
//get rows from offset up to limit
$rows = array_slice($rows, $offset, $limit);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Not sure what `new { records, total }` does in .NET, but you could return one of these:

```
return json_encode([$rows, $total]);
//or
return json_encode(['rows' => $rows, 'total' => $total]);
```

Comment: That only returns the number being returned, I need total number without limit and offset.

Comment: Yes, the first sentence states **If you remove `LIMIT` from the query** so remove LIMIT and that will be the total rows and then you have 2 ways to get the rows you want.

Comment: The problem is the limit and page (offset) are required for pagination but I also need to return the total amount of rows for the query without the limit. I guess I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Edited with a return that looks similar to the .NET one.

Comment: Actually, I changed grids (ShieldUI) and it enabled me to remove the limit and offset for the paging. The grid does it's own paging, which made everything much easier.